# need to add text images button in same canvas on python and different alignment

Tags: python, tkinter

```
Canvass = Canvas(window,height=700,width=1300)

bg = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open('Support_file\\Background.png'))
```

I want to use canvas for adding different element and different alignment, such as few center and few bottom. i try to make it own but could not reach my goal.
Canvass.create_image(0,0,anchor='n',image=bg)

```
IMGS= Image.open('Support_file\\Logo.png')
Reimags= IMGS.resize((280,100),Image.ANTIALIAS)

bg2 = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Reimags)
Canvass.create_image(0,0,anchor='nw',image=bg2)

Canvass.create_text(700,50,text='GSTR Tool Prepare by Visual Data Solution',font=('bold',30))


Canvass.pack()
Canva = Canvas(window,height=100,width=140)



Canva.pack()
```

Comment: *"could not reach my goal"* is not clear enough to tell what your problem is.

Answer (score 0):

> I want to use canvas for adding different element and different
> alignment, such as few center and few bottom.

Is this what you want? I cannot use ImageTk. You can substitute ImageTk to suit your needs.

I just play around with canvas coordinated values.

Code snippet:

```
from tkinter import *
 

win = Tk()

win.geometry("750x250")

canvas= Canvas(win, width= 700, height= 400)
canvas.pack()

img= PhotoImage(file='p1.png')

canvas.create_text(400,200,text='GSTR Tool Prepare by Visual Data Solution',font=('bold',12))
canvas.pack()

canvas.create_image(300, 10, anchor=NW,image=img)

win.mainloop()
```

Screenshot:

[image]